# How would I update a chart within a multi-chart listview?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I've extended the example app `ChartDataAdapater` and `ChartItem`s extensively, but am running into a small issue when it comes to updating already created charts in my listview.

For example, one of the charts in my listview is a linechart with multiple series. I give the user the option to modify the series being displayed, and would like to update the chart on the fly. Right now, I'm adding my charts to the `ArrayList<ChartItem>` like so, and then updating/creating the adapter:

```
this.listChart.add(new LineChartItem(chartdata, getApplicationContext()));
```

`chartdata` will be updated in a background thread, whenever the user changes the series they wish to view..

My question is, how do I reference that `LineChartItem` and update it? Should I be saving a reference to the `LineChartItem` and using that to add to the `ArrayList`? Is there a 'update' method I should be overriding in my `ChartItem` class?

I understand I'll have to update the adapter (notifyDataSetChanged) after I update the `LineChartItem` in my `ArrayList<ChartItem>`, but I seem to having a hard time wrapping my head around the `LineChartItem chartdata` update.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe seems like an issue related to the `ListView` in general.

A solution could be that you somehow remember the index of the item the user is currently working on. Then use that index to get the corresponding data item in your list of data items.

Then udpate that data item with the new data, and refresh the listview.

Comment: Thanks! I came to this epiphany while in the shower earlier today.. not sure why I was thinking the ChartItems would be any different. Thanks again.. for the lib, and the support too! Donation coming your way as soon as I release :)

Comment: Finally got around to trying to implement this today, and ran into a small issue that I can't wrap my head around. Your LineChartItems handle all of the view operations, rather than the adapter... how do i call getItem(position) in the LineChartItem's getView(), like i usually would in the adapter getView()? do I have to create the abstract method in ChartItem? I'm not too familar with abstraction.. reading up now. Thanks again!

Comment: Again, your issues are not related to the library :-)
I suggest that you read a tutorial on the `ListView`. Actually, the chart is just a view like any other view and you can do with it whatever you want. You do not need to rely on my implementation of the listiview with charts in it, as it obviously is not fitting for you.
I would just start from scratch and implement the listivew and it's items in a way that is suitable for you.